# SQL Удалить строку если ключи ссылаются друг на друга

Tags: sql

Как удалить строку, если один из ключей ссылается на строку в другой таблице, а в этой строке другой ключ ссылается на строку которую мы хотим удалить. Без использования CASCADE и других обходных путей.

Comment: cascade - как раз не обходной путь :D а то, что вы ищите - да

Comment: Удалите ограничение. Создайте его снова после удаления строки.